# Is my answer to this Volumes of Revolution question correct?

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid that results when the region under the curve $y = 1 + x^3$ between $x = 1$ and $x = 2$ is revolved about a) the x-axis b) the y-axis.

For part a) since the question is asking in terms of the x-axis and we have an equation in terms of Y, I squared (1+x^3), which gave me this [[integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ7Dg.png)]. My final answer for A got me $\frac{373 \pi}{14}$.

For part b), since the equation is asking in terms of the y-axis and we have an equation in terms of Y, I isolated the X value, which got me this [[X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8pjx.png)]. I substituted this value in the area formula, and solved for the [[integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qigHR.png)], which got me an answer of $\frac{3 \pi}{5}$.

I would like to know if my work and answers are correct. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct. For the second one, around y-axis, it is easier to use shell method.

So, $V = \displaystyle \int_a^b 2 \pi x \ h(x) \ dx = \int_1^2 2 \pi x \ (1+x^3) \ dx = \frac{77 \pi}{5}$

Here is the sketch of the region being rotated around y-axis.

[image]

Comment: Can you also use the disk method to solve this or would you get a different answer? I tried using it but I got an answer of 3/5.

Comment: You can of course use disk method but as you can see that it will have to be split into two integral. For $0 \leq y \leq 2$, we are bound between $x = 1$ and $x = 2$ whereas for $2 \leq y \leq 9$, we are bound between $(y-1)^{1/3} \leq x \leq 2$.

Comment: Here is the right integral for disk method: $\displaystyle \int_0^2 \pi (2^2 - 1^2) \ dy + \int_2^9 \pi (2^2- (y-1)^{2/3}) \ dy$